# Azure Guest OS Family upgrade 2008 to 2012, will deployed apps still work?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I would like to upgrade the "OS Family" of my Azure Cloud Service (Web Role) from "Windows Server 2008 R2" to "Windows Server 2012", so that I have .Net 4.5 available. There is a dropdown in the Azure Portal to make this change, but I am concerned with what kind of outage this may result in... will my deployed website still be active and functional during/after this change?

This is the best documentation I have been able to find and it doesn't mention what behavior I can expect:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456324.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it is understood how Web Roles function, when you upload your application with configurations, Azure saves the uploaded data separate from any virtual machines.  A subsequent deployment of the uploaded application includes creating a brand new virtual machine of your choice (e.g., small, medium,....).  There are separate virtual machines for different Operating Systems.  Once a predefined type virtual machine is provisioned, your app is loaded on the provisioned virtual machine and virtual machine is then started (it is possible that the deployment takes place after starting the VM).  So now, going to back your question, if you change the settings from OS 2008 to OS 2012, it is obvious that the old VM would be de-provisioned and a new VM with OS 2012 is provisioned, your app deployed, etc.  Hence, there will be a downtime.  My experience is that it takes about 5 minutes or so to make this transition.

Comment: I have since deployed this way, and there was indeed only a brief downtime. Overall a great experience.

Comment: By the way, you can change osfamily attribute in cscfg file to 4 to automatically pick Windows Server 2012 R2 upon deployment.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the OS family all the roles and the instances will experience the downtime. This is because OSFamily is part of Services Configuration which is the setting for overall application.  If you have only Web Role or  Worker Role or both in your Azure application changing this setting will applies to all roles and there instances.

Once the configuration changes are applied to the application, the whole services gets updated. Think like this way, if you have multiple instance to a Role, you don't want to run half instance with new configuration and half older configuration, as this may create big problem. So updating application configuration required does required downtime. There is already staging and production slot based deployment available to reduce downtime.

If you want to avoid down time you can do the following:

1. While your production application already running, deploy your new application with OSFamily=3 (Windows Server 2012) to staging slot
2. Test staging application as needed
3. Once your staging application works as expected do  "VIP SWAP" at the portal. 
   VIP swap will push your staging deployment to production and within less then second you will have application running with Windows Server 2012.

Comment: If I don't go the VIP swap method, and initiate the upgrade in place, will it bring my app up on the new environment automatically or will I have to redeploy?

Comment: If you update your application with in-place, your VM will have new Os family you selected and then your application will run it it and you don't need to redeploy it. Be sure to have test your application in Windows Server 2012 to make sure your app has no surprises for you.